# matlab - find index for when values exceeds a threshold n number of times

Tags: matlab, find

I would like to find the index for when an array exceeds a certain value, and this value is value is exceeded for a duration, n. For examples:

```
n = 5;
dat = [1,2,2,1.5,2,4,2,1,1,3,4,6,8,4,9];
```

Here, I would like to find when 'dat' exceeds 2 for a duration greater than n for the first time. So, the solution here should lead to an answer:

```
ans = 10
```

Another example:

```
n = 7;
dat = [1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,9,6,4,3,2,4,6,7,7,5];
```

find the first time that 'dat' exceeds or equals 5 for more than or equal to n times.

ans = 6

Comment: You might want to say "Here, I would like to find when 'dat' exceeds `or equals` 2 for a duration greater than n for the first time."

Comment: I stand by my answer then (edited to reflect the new 'or equals' clause). I see you add a cast to double in my answer, I can't check it in matlab right now but I don't think it's needed. Does matlab really throw an error without it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
n = 5;
m = 2;
dat = [1,2,2,1.5,2,4,2,1,1,3,4,6,8,4,9];

c = conv(double(dat >= m), ones(1, n))
%I think you can also do
%  c = conv((dat >= m)*1, ones(1, n))

min(find(c == n)) - n + 1
```

Comment: If I copy this straight into Matlab I receive the error: Error using conv2
First and second arguments must be single or double.

Error in conv (line 39)
c = conv2(a(:),b(:),shape);

Comment: Only tested it in octave (where it works) but very surprised by it not working in matlab. I'll add the casting you suggested. Possible alternative to casting is just to `.*1` I think, might be worth trying that too.

Answer (score 1):

```
n=5
x=2;
dat = [1,2,2,1.5,2,4,2,1,1,3,4,6,8,4,9];
vec= cumsum(dat>=x);
ind=find(vec>=n);
ind=dat(ind(1));
```

`ind` will contain the answer 10

Comment: We have very different interpretations of this question. I think OP means that there will be 5 elements in a row greater than 2 i.e. (3, 4, 6, 8, 4). OP needs to clarify with a second example maybe.

Comment: @Dan Ok. I understand. He wants the value not the index. I interpreted "find the first time" as finding the index. Answer edited. Also note that now it is `>=x` as well as `>=n`. So his first and second example has different wordings. My answer is according to the latest example he has given.