# Max Series of Consecutive Numbers

Tags: arrays, matlab

I need help finding a way to do this, although it seems as it should be pretty simple. Lets say I have a `nx1` array. For example, let `X=[1 1 1 .5 .4 .2 -.2 -.3 1 1 0 1]`. What I am trying to do is find where the greatest series of consecutive `1`'s begins and how many `1`'s are in it. For instance, using `X`, the greatest series of consecutive series starts at the index 1 and is of length 3. Also, I will be using very large sets of data so I would like to try and find the most efficient and fastest way this can be done.

Comment: possible duplicate of [matlab - find index for when values exceeds a threshold n number of times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15519695/matlab-find-index-for-when-values-exceeds-a-threshold-n-number-of-times)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way that you could accomplish that fairly efficiently:

```
x = [1 1 1 0.5 0.4 0.2 -0.2 -0.3 1 1 0 1];
x1 = (x==1);
d = diff(x1(:).');
start = find([x1(1) d]==1)
len = find([d -x1(end)]==-1)-start+1
```

which returns

```
start =

     1     9    12

len =

     3     2     1
```

Comment: I tweaked the code to make work for both row- and column-vector inputs.

Comment: No I am just passing through a column vector. However, the loop is returning empty matrices, even though there are consecutive 1's in the column.

Comment: What vector for example? And are you sure that those values are actually `==1` and not off by some epsilon? If they are just very very close to `1` then you you should be able to adapt the equation for `x1` in my code above to include a small tolerance.

Comment: Thank you! That worked by adjusting it to x>=.9. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Good to hear. A more general solution would be `x1 = (abs(x-1)<tol);`, which would allow you specify a tolerance value `tol` as needed.

Answer (score 0):

A function like this can help

```
function [start, len] = findLongestRunning(x)
y = find(diff([0;x(:)==1;0]));
[len,J] = max(y(2:2:end)-y(1:2:end));
start = y(2*J(1)-1);
end
```

Running on your example

```
>> [start, len] = findLongestRunning(x)
start =
     1
len =
     3
```

Note that the code returns the first occurence if there are more than one sequence meeting the requirements:

```
>> [start, len] = findLongestRunning([x 0 x])
start =
     1
len =
     3
```