# Count number of bouts separated by zeros

Tags: matlab, count, zero

I have a vector like this:

```
A = [1 2 1 1 1 4 5 0 0 1 2 0 2 3 2 2 2 0 0 0 0 33]
```

I would like to count how many GROUPS of non zero elements it contains and save them.

so I want to isolate:

> [1 2 1 1 1 4 5]
>
> [1 2]
>
> [2 3 2 2 2]
>
> [33]

and then count the groups (they should be 4) :)

Can you help me please?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To count your groups, a fast vectorized method using [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1) is:

```
count = sum(diff([A 0]==0)==1)
```

This assumes that `A` is a row vector as in your example. This works with no zeros, all zeros, the empty vector, and several other test cases I tried.

To obtain your groups of values themselves, you can use a variation to [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643016/max-series-of-consecutive-numbers/17643333#17643333):

```
a0 = (A~=0);
d = diff(a0);
start = find([a0(1) d]==1)           % Start index of each group
len = find([d -a0(end)]==-1)-start+1 % Length, number of indexes in each group
```

In your case it might make sense to replace `len` with

```
finish = find([d -a0(end)]==-1) % Last index of each group
```

The `length` of `start`, `len`, and `finish` should be the same as the value of `count` so you could just use this if you need to do the breaking up. You can then use `start` and `len` (or `finish`) to store your groups in a cell array or struct or some other ragged array. For example:

```
count = length(start);
B = cell(count,1);
for i = 1:count
    B{i} = A(start(i):finish(i));
end
```

Comment: thanks! and is there as well a way to split them in a fast way? My real vector contains up to 10000 elements...

Comment: ok I'll have a look and eventually ask a separate question thanks! 
ps yes this calculation is inside a for loop...

Comment: @gabboshow: I see that you kind of did ask about breaking into groups too so I've edited my answer to add that part.

Comment: @gabboshow: Great. Sorry about the initial misunderstanding of the question. Things move too fast around here.