# Find locations of "TRUE" clusters in a vector of logicals

Tags: matlab

I have the following vector of logicals:

```
vect1 = [0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1]
```

I would like to locate all the `1` value "clusters" within this vector along with their starting and ending indices.  For output, I would like to be able to come up with something like:

```
5 8
13 15
18 19
23 23
```

where the first number is the "starting" index of each cluster and the second number is the "ending" index of each cluster.

EDIT: I was able to get this to work with a modified version of Shai's answer:

```
pv = [vect1 0];
sv = [0 pv(1:(end-1))];
ev = [pv(2:end) 0];
starting = find( pv - sv == 1 )
ending = find( pv - ev == 1 )
```

Comment: Anything wrong with my working answer? Also using `diff` is going to be much more efficient if your vectors are large.

Comment: Interesting, I haven't tested larger vectors (which are in fact what I will be using this on).  I will have to test those and will let you know.  Thanks again!

Comment: I created a vector with 100,000 elements (`vect1 = randi([0 1], 1, 100000)`), and then ran both solutions in a for loop with 1,000 iterations.  Your updated answer took 2.3 seconds to execute; Shai's took 1.6 (on repeated tries).  100,000 is about the size of my vectors.  Am I still missing something?  Thank you once again

Comment: Same test (with code that outputs a matrix as in your question): 2.1415 and 2.1419. These things are version- and OS- and hardware-dependent. You also must time properly or you're measuring the wrong thing -variables must be cleared between calling each version and you should "warm up" by calling the code before timing it. More important: use the code that works for you and that you understand.

Comment: Could you test the speed of my version posted below too? It avoids some of the copying done in the other solutions and only uses a single find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To handle the last 1, it would be simpler to pad the vector with a zero:

```
pv = [vect1 0];
sv = [0 pv];
ev = [pv(2:end) 0];
starting = find( pv - sv == 1 );
ending = find( pv - sv == -1 );
```

Comment: The code gave me a `Matrix dimensions must agree.` error, so I made some modifications and posted them above.  Please let me know if you agree with those.

Answer (score 4):

This question is nearly a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870481/count-number-of-bouts-separated-by-zeros/17870575#17870575). Adapting my answer from there:

```
vect1 = [0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1];
v1 = (vect1(:)==1);
d = diff(v1);
output = [find([v1(1);d]==1) find([d;-v1(end)]==-1)]
```

which returns

```
output =

     5     8
    13    15
    18    19
    23    23
```

The two calls to `find` can be reduced to one with

```
[output,~] = find([[v1(1);d] [-d;v1(end)]]==1);
output = reshape(output,[length(output)/2 2]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  This also works, but Shai's solution is significantly faster (I need to run this code many times).

Comment: Significantly?? I just tested and actually couldn't tell the difference. In any case, `diff` is supposed to be faster (multi-core optimized, etc.), but maybe for simple cases the JIT in recent versions can do a good job. It must be smart enough to figure out that two vector-vector subtractions are identical.

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest one liner I could think of

```
out =  [find(diff([0 vect1 0])==1); find(diff([0 vect1 0])==-1)-1]'
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a run length encoding function on the Matlab file exchange that I use for this sort of problem. The benefit of this solution (i.e. the rle function) is that it finds repeated blocks without prior knowledge of which values will be repeated.

```
encoded = rle(vect1);
summed = cumsum(encoded{2});
isOne = encoded{1}==1;
[summed(isOne)-encoded{2}(isOne)+1;  summed(isOne)]'
```

See:
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4955-rle-deencoding

Alternatively (and slightly faster)

```
blockEnds = [ find(vect1(1:end-1) ~= vect1(2:end)) length(vect1) ];
blockStarts = [ 1 blockEnds(1:end-1)+1];
isOne = vect1(blockEnds)==1;
[blockStarts(isOne); blockEnds(isOne)]'
```