# finding indeces of similar group elements

Tags: matlab, indexing, grouping

I have a vector `test2` that includes `NaN 0` and `1` in random order (we cannot make any assumption).

```
test2 = [NaN 1 1 1 0 0 0 NaN NaN NaN 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 ];
```

I would like to group the elements containing consecutive `1` and to have in the separte vectors `start` and `finish` the first and last index of the groups.

In this case `start` and `finish` should be:

```
start = [2 14 18];
finish = [4 16 20];
```

I tried to adapt the code provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870481/count-number-of-bouts-separated-by-zeros) coming up with this solution that is not working...could you help me with the right solution and tell me why the one I tried doesn't work?

```
a = (test2 ==1);
d = diff(a);
start = find([a(1) d]==1);                        % Start index of each group
finish = find([d - a(end)]==-1);                  % Last index of each group


start =

     2    14    18


finish =

     2     3     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12    14    15    18    19
```

I am using MATLAB R2013b running on Windows.
I tried also using MATLAB R2013a running on ubuntu.

Comment: With this exact code I get the expected output.

Comment: finish should be [4 16 20], I am using Matab R2013b

Comment: Yep that's what I get for `finish` (and `start` is `[2 14 18]`)

Comment: I tried again....I get finish = 2     3     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12    14    15    18    19

Comment: that's weird... I tried also with Ubuntu...same wrong result..

Comment: Mhh weird indeed I don't understand. I'm using R2013a on Mac OSX...but that should not make a difference...hopefully someone will see what's going on

Comment: I get the same output as the OP - MATLAB R2013a - Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.3. My guess is that it may be the `NaN` that is missing things up.  Try replacing `NaN` with something else.

Comment: and also with a scalar...

Comment: I think you may have a typo with this `d-a(end)` since a(end) is 1 it makes `[d - a(end)]` contain a bunch of -1...which is what you are searching for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a = (test2 ==1)
d=diff([0 a 0])
start=find(d==1)
finish=find(d==-1)-1
```

Padding a zero at the beginning and end is the easiest possibility. Then the special cases where a group starts at index 1 or ends at last index don't cause problems.

Full output:

```
>> test2 = [NaN 1 1 1 0 0 0 NaN NaN NaN 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 ]

test2 =

  Columns 1 through 16

   NaN     1     1     1     0     0     0   NaN   NaN   NaN     0     0     0     1     1     1

  Columns 17 through 20

     0     1     1     1

>> a = (test2 ==1)

a =

  Columns 1 through 16

     0     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1

  Columns 17 through 20

     0     1     1     1

>> d=diff([0 a 0])

d =

  Columns 1 through 16

     0     1     0     0    -1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0

  Columns 17 through 21

    -1     1     0     0    -1

>> start=find(d==1)

start =

     2    14    18

>> finish=find(d==-1)-1

finish =

     4    16    20

>>
```

Comment: using the solution that you provided I get   start = 3    15    19 and finish =   0     2     3     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12    14    15    18    19

Comment: @gabboshow: I added the full output of my command prompt, could you compare it with your output? No idea where the difference occurs.

Comment: Thanks! it works! I think before I modified my solution...using your code (different from mine) I get the desired result...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the line `finish = find([d - a(end)]==-1);`, in particular that `a(end) == 1`. There are two steps to correcting this. First, change the problem line to `finish = find(d==-1);` This tells MATLAB, "Look for the elements where the difference between adjacent elements is -1". In other words, the vector shifts from 1 to 0 or NaN. If you run the code, you'll get

```
start =  2    14    18
finish = 4    16
```

Now, you'll notice the last element isn't detected (i.e. we should get `finish(3) == 20`. This is because the length of `d` is one less than the length of `test2`; the function `diff` cannot calculate the difference between the last element and the non-existant last+1 element!

To remedy this, we should modify `a`:

```
a = [(test2 == 1) 0];
```

And you will get the right output for `start` and `finish`.