# Consolidate Number of Groups Separated by Zeros

Tags: matlab

I am recording from an analog device, and assuming the data resembles an example vector like:

```
A = [1 4 2 0 4 5 8 8 1 0 0 0 4 7 1 9 0 0 0 8 1 2]
```

I would like to:

1) Count the number of groups of non-zero elements
2) Consolidate the groups that might belong to the same condition

For 1), we might split it into

1 4 2
4 5 8 8 1
4 7 1 9
8 1 2

However, for 2), there is a chance that the values separated by the first, single 0 is actually from the same condition compared to the values separated by more zeros, which means that the vector might be actually split into

1 4 2 4 5 8 8 1
4 7 1 9
8 1 2

A past solution for (1) can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870481/count-number-of-bouts-separated-by-zeros), which is:

```
count = sum(diff([A 0]==0)==1)
a0 = (A~=0);
d = diff(a0);
start = find([a0(1) d]==1)           % Start index of each group
len = find([d -a0(end)]==-1)-start+1 % Length, number of indexes in each group
finish = find([d -a0(end)]==-1)      % Last index of each group
count = length(start);
B = cell(count,1);
for i = 1:count
B{i} = A(start(i):finish(i));
```

Since I didn't want to necro an old thread, I was wondering if there is a way to make the grouping more robust so that values that are separated by single or double zeros are not split off into an entirely new group.

Comment: Ben, can you give us some more info regarding `A`? Which range of values will it contain? Just integers from 0 to 9?

Comment: @Alessiox Sorry, I should've given a more realistic example. They are actually non-integers, like 

 `A = [0.01 0.04 0.02 0.00 0.04 0.05 0.08 0.08 0.01 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.04 0.07 0.01 0.09 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.08 0.01 0.02]`

Each actual row contains between 5k-10k values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The case of integer values in range [0:9]**

There is a very elegant one-line solution using regular expressions.
First of all convert the vector as a string:

```
A = [1 4 2 0 4 5 8 8 1 0 0 0 4 7 1 9 0 0 0 8 1 2];
As=num2str(A);
As(As==' ')=[];
```

the last line is mandatory due to the fact that `num2str()` also converts blank spaces between numbers. Therefore `As` will have the form:

```
As =

1420458810004719000812
```

and will be a string.

Now the `regexp()`:

```
out = regexp(As,'0{2,}','split');
```

Such expression basically says: from `As` grab the indices in which there are two or more consecutive zeros and return (thanks to `split`) the non-matching sequences (i.e. we do not what the zeros, we want the non-zeros part of the sequence).

However, `out` will be a cell array due to the fact that `As` is a string. If you want it back to numeric, just add:

```
out=cellfun(@str2num,out);
```

in order to convert the cell array with strings into a matrix (with numbers of course). Indeed now `out` has the form:

```
out =

   142045881        4719         812
```

**The floating point case**

```
A = [0.01 0.04 0.02 0.00 0.04 0.05 0.08 0.08 0.01 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.04 0.07 0.01 0.09 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.08 0.01 0.02];
As=num2str(A);
As(As==' ')=[];
```

Now `As` has the form:

```
As =

0.010.040.0200.040.050.080.080.010000.040.070.010.090000.080.010.02
```

The two or more zeros are now hard to find. However, patterns emerge: such set of zeros have a non-zero number before (the last decimal from previous number) and have another zero after (if it was a "normal" zero it'd have a decimal point)

```
[sID,eID]=regexp(As,'[1-9]00{2,}');
```

where `sID` and `eID` are the start and end indices of our substring target(s), respectively [1]. Now let's split `As` thanks to the above indices [2]:

```
C{1}=As(1:sID(1));
for ii=2:length(sID)
    C{end+1}=As(eID(ii-1):sID(ii));
end
C{end+1}=As(eID(end):end);
```

The cell array `C` now is rather messy due to the fact that there's no such thing as `0.00` or even `000` because Matlab treat `0.00` as simply `0` but we must append a `.00` in order to rebuild the original sequence:

```
for i=1:length(C)
    idx=strfind(C{i},'00');
    if isempty(idx)==false
        C{i}=[C{i}(1:idx) '.00' C{i}(idx+1:end)];
    end
    C{i}=reshape(C{i},4,[])';
end
```

In the above code, we also reshaped the long strings into matrices, so now we can easily convert them into numeric

```
C1=cellfun(@str2num,C,'UniformOutput',0);
```

Now `C1` is still a cell array where every cell is a chunk of sequence (in numeric array form). Obviously now we cannot rely on matrices and we are forced to use cell arrays due to the fact that chunks might have different lengths.

**Final note**

If `A` has numbers in range {0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08 0.09} you can as well multiply `A` by 100: in that case `A` will be a vector of integers and you can easily use the more elegant Integer approach. Then you can convert them back to floating point using this little snippet:

```
for ii=1:length(out)
    out{ii}=num2str(out{ii});                             %convert to string, so we can enumerate and treat digits separately
    out{ii}=[repmat('0.0',length(out{ii}),1) out{ii}(:)]; %put '0.0' in front of every number
    out{ii}=str2num(out{ii});                             %roll-back to numeric
end
```

It is finally worth noticing that given the `A` definition as in the beginning of *The floating point case* both the floating point case itself and the latter lead to the same results.

[1] suggested by @LuisMendo
[2] improved thanks to @Adiel

Comment: Nice approach! But there's a problem if entries of `A` exceed 9, or are negative, or non-integer

Comment: @LuisMendo, well I've just worked on the provided example. Let's hear some more from the OP

Comment: @LuisMendo you were right then, there are floating point numbers. I reckon I'll update my answer asap or fell free to propose your own, I'll remove mine

Comment: Maybe you can maintain the regexp approach to get the _indices_ into the original vector

Comment: @LuisMendo, that's tricky. the `0.00` in `A` (see OP's comment) will be converted to `0` and the `regexp()` will fail.

Comment: Very nice, I liked the approach, the implement, and the later fix! BTW, the loop for constructing `C` would be more clean/readable if c{1} would be defined before the loop, and then `for i=2:length(sID)` (and don't use `i` as a variable... :)  )

Comment: @Adiel, thanks for the feedback. Code improved. I'll never stop using `i` as a variable for the for-loop I'm afraid, it's in my blood now. I reckon that's why Mathworks now has `1!` for the imaginary unit: because people like me can't be cured.

Comment: Thanks for the credit about so unnecessary part of that beautiful answer :)  After I read the discussion here- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab  about using `i,j`, I tried to stop this practice, and get used very fast to `k` ...

Comment: @Alessiox Thanks for the help, I really like the approach! I'll also see if I can round the numbers to fewer significant figures and try out that integer method too.